# Trying to make a list to free allocated memory but I get a access violation when getting trying to free

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I made a list called mallocKillList which is a void double pointer that stores all the allocated memory then is suppose to free it at the end. But when I try to free the memory on the first index of the loop I get this error "Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA8523C55C (ucrtbased.dll) in NeuralNetworkC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF."

The code is complex to the point where its hard for me to make a minimal reproducible example so the projects code is following the method where the error is occurring is mallocDestroyer().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//Variable to store the length of the mallocKillList because you can get the length of a heap allocated array - Christian Phillips
unsigned int mallocKillListLength = 2;
//void** to store all the pointers that need to be freed at the end of the program - Christian Phillips
void** mallocKillList = NULL;

//Beggining of RandomNumberGen.h

//this is used as the seed for the random number generator - Christian Phillips
unsigned long seed;

//Function that returns the max value that can be stored in a uLong - Christian Phillips
unsigned long getMaxULongValue()
{
    unsigned long uLongLength = 0;
    uLongLength = ~uLongLength;
    return uLongLength;
}

//Function that returns the max value that can be stored in a uInt - Christian Phillips
unsigned int getMaxUIntValue()
{
    unsigned int uIntLength = 0;
    uIntLength = ~uIntLength;
    return uIntLength;
}

//Sets the seed for the random number gen - Christian Phillips
void setRandSeed(unsigned long inputSeed)
{
    seed = inputSeed;
}

//Function to generate pseudo-random ints - Christian Phillips
unsigned int genRandInt()
{
    seed = (561 * seed + 33) % getMaxULongValue();
    return seed % getMaxUIntValue();
}

//Ending of RandomNumberGen.h


//Make Structures for the nodes, rawNodes and weights of the network - Christian Phillips

//Structure for input nodes probaly could have just used an array of floats - Christian Phillips
struct inputNode
{
    float value;
};

//This is the structure for the raw hidden nodes stores the value the bias and the partial derivative of its parent node with respect to itself - Christian Phillips
struct rawHiddenNode
{
    float value;
    float bias;
    float pDerivative;
};

struct rawOutputNode
{
    float value;
    float bias;
    float* pDerivatives;
};

struct hiddenNode
{
    float value;
    float* pDerivatives;
};

struct outputNode
{
    float value;
};

struct weight
{
    float value;
    float pDerivative;
    void* parentNode;
    void* childNode;
};

float relu(float num)
{
    if (num >= 0)
    {
        return num;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0.0f;
    }
}

//Make a struct for the Neural Network - Christian Phillips
struct NeuralNetwork
{
    //Variables to set the number of nodes and layers - Christian Phillips
    unsigned int numInputNodes;
    unsigned int numHiddenLayers;
    unsigned int numOutputNodes;
    unsigned int* hiddenLayers;

    //Variables to store the values of the nodes - Christian Phillips
    struct inputNode* inputNodes;
    struct rawHiddenNode** rawHiddenNodes;
    struct hiddenNode** hiddenNodes;
    struct rawOutputNode* rawOutputNodes;
    struct outputNode* outputNodes;

    //Variables for the weights between the layers - Christian Phillips
    struct weight** weightsInput_Hidden;
    struct weight*** weightsHidden_Hidden;
    struct weight** weightsHidden_Output;
};

//This is the method to perform the soft max activation function on the raw Output nodes which calculates the output nodes it takes the pointer to the neural network and the index for which output node is being calculated
float softMax(struct NeuralNetwork* pNetwork, unsigned int outputNodeIndex)
{
    float sumRawOuputs = 0.0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < pNetwork->numOutputNodes; i++)
    {
        sumRawOuputs += (float)exp(pNetwork->rawOutputNodes[i].value);
    }

    return (float)exp(pNetwork->rawOutputNodes[outputNodeIndex].value) / sumRawOuputs;
}

//This is an importaint function that adds 
int addMallocKill(void* ptr)
{
    if (mallocKillList == NULL)
    {
        mallocKillList = (void**)malloc(sizeof(void*) * mallocKillListLength);

        if (mallocKillList == NULL)
        {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        mallocKillList[0] = ptr;

        for (int i = 1; i < mallocKillListLength; i++)
        {
            mallocKillList[i] = NULL;
        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    else if (mallocKillList[mallocKillListLength - 1] != NULL)
    {
        void** newMallocKillList = (void**)malloc(sizeof(void*) * (mallocKillListLength + 1));

        if (newMallocKillList == NULL)
        {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < mallocKillListLength; i++)
        {
            newMallocKillList[i] = mallocKillList[i];
        }

        mallocKillListLength = mallocKillListLength + 1;

        free(mallocKillList);

        mallocKillList = newMallocKillList;

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < mallocKillListLength; i++)
        {
            if (mallocKillList[i] == NULL)
            {
                mallocKillList[i] = ptr;
                break;
            }
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}

//function to act like a constructor for the Neural Network
struct NeuralNetwork* constructNeuralNetwork(unsigned int numIN, unsigned int* HL, unsigned int numON, unsigned int numHL)
{
    struct NeuralNetwork* pNetwork = (struct NeuralNetwork*)malloc(sizeof(struct NeuralNetwork));
    addMallocKill(pNetwork);

    if (pNetwork == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    pNetwork->numInputNodes = numIN;
    pNetwork->hiddenLayers = HL;
    pNetwork->numOutputNodes = numON;
    pNetwork->numHiddenLayers = numHL;

    pNetwork->inputNodes = (struct inputNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct inputNode) * numIN);
    addMallocKill(pNetwork->inputNodes);

    pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes = (struct rawHiddenNode**)malloc(sizeof(struct rawHiddenNode*) * numHL);
    addMallocKill(pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes);

    for (int i = 0; i < numHL; i++)
    {
        pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes[i] = (struct rawHiddenNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct rawHiddenNode) * HL[i]);
    }

    pNetwork->hiddenNodes = (struct hiddenNode**)malloc(sizeof(struct hiddenNode*) * numHL);
    addMallocKill(pNetwork->hiddenNodes);

    for (int i = 0; i < numHL; i++)
    {
        pNetwork->hiddenNodes[i] = (struct hiddenNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct hiddenNode) * HL[i]);
        addMallocKill(pNetwork->hiddenNodes[i]);
    }

    pNetwork->rawOutputNodes = (struct rawOutputNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct rawOutputNode) * numON);
    addMallocKill(pNetwork->rawOutputNodes);
    pNetwork->outputNodes = (struct outputNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct outputNode) * numON);
    addMallocKill(pNetwork->outputNodes);

    setWeights(pNetwork);

    return pNetwork;
}

int setWeights(struct NeuralNetwork* pNetwork)
{
    //float used to store the result of the formula used to calculate the weight
    float randFloat = 0.0;

    pNetwork->weightsInput_Hidden = (struct weight**)malloc(sizeof(struct weight*) * pNetwork->numInputNodes);
    addMallocKill(pNetwork->weightsInput_Hidden);

    for (int i = 0; i < pNetwork->numInputNodes; i++)
    {
        pNetwork->weightsInput_Hidden[i] = (struct weight*)malloc(sizeof(struct weight) * pNetwork->hiddenLayers[0]);
        addMallocKill(pNetwork->weightsInput_Hidden[i]);
    }

    pNetwork->weightsHidden_Hidden = (struct weight***)malloc(sizeof(struct weight**) * (pNetwork->numHiddenLayers - 1));
    addMallocKill(pNetwork->weightsHidden_Hidden);

    for (int i = 0; i < pNetwork->numHiddenLayers - 1; i++)
    {
        pNetwork->weightsHidden_Hidden[i] = (struct weight**)malloc(sizeof(struct weight*) * pNetwork->hiddenLayers[i]);
        addMallocKill(pNetwork->weightsHidden_Hidden[i]);

        for (int j = 0; j < pNetwork->hiddenLayers[i]; j++)
        {
            pNetwork->weightsHidden_Hidden[i][j] = (struct weight*)malloc(sizeof(struct weight) * pNetwork->hiddenLayers[i + 1]);
            addMallocKill(pNetwork->weightsHidden_Hidden[i][j]);
        }
    }

    pNetwork->weightsHidden_Output = (struct weight**)malloc(sizeof(struct weight*) * pNetwork->hiddenLayers[pNetwork->numHiddenLayers - 1]);
    addMallocKill(pNetwork->weightsHidden_Output);

    for (int i = 0; i < pNetwork->hiddenLayers[pNetwork->numHiddenLayers - 1]; i++)
    {
        pNetwork->weightsHidden_Output[i] = (struct weight*)malloc(sizeof(struct weight) * pNetwork->numOutputNodes);
        addMallocKill(pNetwork->weightsHidden_Output[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pNetwork->numInputNodes; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pNetwork->hiddenLayers[0]; j++)
        {
            randFloat = (genRandInt() % 100) / 100.0f - 0.5f;
            pNetwork->weightsInput_Hidden[i][j].value = randFloat;
            pNetwork->weightsInput_Hidden[i][j].parentNode = &(pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes[0][j]);
            pNetwork->weightsInput_Hidden[i][j].childNode = &(pNetwork->inputNodes[i]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pNetwork->numHiddenLayers - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pNetwork->hiddenLayers[i]; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < pNetwork->hiddenLayers[i + 1]; k++)
            {
                randFloat = (genRandInt() % 100) / 100.0f - 0.5f;
                pNetwork->weightsHidden_Hidden[i][j][k].value = randFloat;
                pNetwork->weightsHidden_Hidden[i][j][k].parentNode = &(pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes[i + 1][k]);
                pNetwork->weightsHidden_Hidden[i][j][k].childNode = &(pNetwork->hiddenNodes[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pNetwork->hiddenLayers[pNetwork->numHiddenLayers - 1]; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pNetwork->numOutputNodes; j++)
        {
            randFloat = (genRandInt() % 100) / 100.0f - 0.5f;
            pNetwork->weightsHidden_Output[i][j].value = randFloat;
            pNetwork->weightsHidden_Output[i][j].parentNode = &(pNetwork->rawOutputNodes[j]);
            pNetwork->weightsHidden_Output[i][j].childNode = &(pNetwork->hiddenNodes[pNetwork->numHiddenLayers - 1][i]);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int calcWeightDerivatives(struct NeuralNetwork* pNetwork)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pNetwork->numInputNodes; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pNetwork->hiddenLayers[0]; j++)
        {
            pNetwork->weightsInput_Hidden[i][j].pDerivative = *((float*)pNetwork->weightsInput_Hidden[i][j].childNode);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pNetwork->numHiddenLayers - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pNetwork->hiddenLayers[i]; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < pNetwork->hiddenLayers[i + 1]; k++)
            {
                pNetwork->weightsHidden_Hidden[i][j][k].pDerivative = *((float*)pNetwork->weightsHidden_Hidden[i][j][k].childNode);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pNetwork->hiddenLayers[pNetwork->numHiddenLayers - 1]; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pNetwork->numOutputNodes; j++)
        {
            pNetwork->weightsHidden_Output[i][j].pDerivative = *((float*)pNetwork->weightsHidden_Output[i][j].childNode);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int setBiases(struct NeuralNetwork* pNetwork)
{
    if (pNetwork == NULL || pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes == NULL || pNetwork->rawOutputNodes == NULL)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pNetwork->numHiddenLayers; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pNetwork->hiddenLayers[i]; j++)
        {
            pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes[i][j].bias = 0.0f;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pNetwork->numOutputNodes; i++)
    {
        pNetwork->rawOutputNodes[i].bias = 0.0f;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int setInputNodes(struct NeuralNetwork* pNetwork, float* inputs, unsigned int inputLength)
{
    if (pNetwork->numInputNodes != inputLength)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (pNetwork == NULL || pNetwork->inputNodes == NULL)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pNetwork->numInputNodes; i++)
    {
        pNetwork->inputNodes[i].value = inputs[i];
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int calcHiddenNodes(struct NeuralNetwork* pNetwork)
{
    if (pNetwork == NULL || pNetwork->inputNodes == NULL || pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes == NULL)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pNetwork->hiddenLayers[0]; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pNetwork->numInputNodes; j++)
        {
            pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes[0][i].value += pNetwork->inputNodes[j].value * pNetwork->weightsInput_Hidden[j][i].value;
        }

        pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes[0][i].value += pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes[0][i].bias;
        pNetwork->hiddenNodes[0][i].value = relu(pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes[0][i].value);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pNetwork->numHiddenLayers - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pNetwork->hiddenLayers[i + 1]; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < pNetwork->hiddenLayers[i]; k++)
            {
                pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes[i + 1][j].value += pNetwork->hiddenNodes[i][k].value * pNetwork->weightsHidden_Hidden[i][k][j].value;
            }

            pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes[i + 1][j].value += pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes[i + 1][j].bias;
            pNetwork->hiddenNodes[i + 1][j].value = relu(pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes[i + 1][j].value);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int calcHiddenDerivates(struct NeuralNetwork* pNetwork)
{
    if (pNetwork == NULL || pNetwork->inputNodes == NULL || pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes == NULL)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pNetwork->numHiddenLayers; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pNetwork->hiddenLayers[i]; j++)
        {
            if (pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes[i][j].value > 0)
            {
                pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes[i][j].pDerivative = 1.0f;
            }
            else
            {
                pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes[i][j].pDerivative = 0.0f;
            }

            if ((i + 1) < pNetwork->numHiddenLayers)
            {
                pNetwork->hiddenNodes[i][j].pDerivatives = (float*)malloc(sizeof(pNetwork->hiddenNodes[i + 1][0].value) * pNetwork->hiddenLayers[i + 1]);
                addMallocKill(pNetwork->hiddenNodes[i][j].pDerivatives);

                for (int k = 0; k < pNetwork->hiddenLayers[i + 1]; k++)
                {
                    pNetwork->hiddenNodes[i][j].pDerivatives[k] = pNetwork->weightsHidden_Hidden[i][j][k].value;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                pNetwork->hiddenNodes[i][j].pDerivatives = (float*)malloc(sizeof(pNetwork->outputNodes[0].value) * pNetwork->numOutputNodes);
                addMallocKill(pNetwork->hiddenNodes[i][j].pDerivatives);

                for (int k = 0; k < pNetwork->numOutputNodes; k++)
                {
                    pNetwork->hiddenNodes[i][j].pDerivatives[k] = pNetwork->weightsHidden_Output[j][k].value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int calcOutputNodes(struct NeuralNetwork* pNetwork)
{
    if (pNetwork == NULL || pNetwork->rawOutputNodes == NULL || pNetwork->outputNodes == NULL)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pNetwork->numOutputNodes; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pNetwork->hiddenLayers[pNetwork->numHiddenLayers - 1]; j++)
        {
            pNetwork->rawOutputNodes[i].value += pNetwork->hiddenNodes[pNetwork->numHiddenLayers - 1][j].value * pNetwork->weightsHidden_Output[j][i].value;
        }

        pNetwork->rawOutputNodes[i].value += pNetwork->rawOutputNodes[i].bias;
        pNetwork->outputNodes[i].value = softMax(pNetwork, i);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int calcOutputDerivates(struct NeuralNetwork* pNetwork)
{
    if (pNetwork == NULL || pNetwork->rawOutputNodes == NULL || pNetwork->outputNodes == NULL)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }



    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int mallocDestroyer()
{
    if (mallocKillList == NULL)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    for (int i = mallocKillListLength - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        free(mallocKillList[i]);
    }

    free(mallocKillList);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int* hiddenLayers = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    addMallocKill(hiddenLayers);

    float* inputs = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * 3);
    addMallocKill(inputs);

    inputs[0] = 0.1f;
    inputs[1] = 0.2f;
    inputs[2] = 0.3f;

    hiddenLayers[0] = 2;
    hiddenLayers[1] = 2;

    struct NeuralNetwork* pNetwork = constructNeuralNetwork(3, hiddenLayers, 3, 2);

    setInputNodes(pNetwork, inputs, 3);
    calcHiddenNodes(pNetwork);
    calcOutputNodes(pNetwork);

    printf("weight: %f", pNetwork->weightsInput_Hidden[0][0].value);
    printf("weight: %f", pNetwork->weightsInput_Hidden[1][0].value);
    printf("weight: %f", pNetwork->weightsInput_Hidden[2][0].value);
    printf("first output node: %f", pNetwork->outputNodes[0].value);

    mallocDestroyer();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You talk about a "list" but `mallocKillList` appears to be an array. This naming is at least mildly confusing.

Comment: It looks like you're creating an array of void pointers, but when this array reaches its capacity, you need it to grow, so you `malloc` a new array and copy everything over. Why not just use `realloc` which can handle the copying and freeing of old memory (if necessary) for you?

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: @chis When I was looking for answers online I did see that in one of them and I was going to look into it. I am a beginner at c so I just learned how to use malloc.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc

Comment: As an added tip, you generally don't want to grow such an expanding array by adding one. This results in a lot of extra allocations and copying. Opinions vary between 2x and 1.5x, but either is vastly better than just adding room for one pointer at a time.

Comment: I did think about this but the way the I implemented the memory freeing is I start from the end of the array to the beginning which would try to free a NULL.

Comment: Actually I remeber I learned that freeing a NULL would do nothing so it doesnt matter anyway I originaly had it where it muliplied the current length of the array by 2. I will just do that again.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing your addMallocKill and mallocDestroyer functions like below to resolve your problems:

```
void mallocDestroyer()
{
    int i;

    if (!mallocKillList)
        return;

    for (i = 0; i < mallocKillListLength; i++) {
        free(mallocKillList[i]);
    }

    free(mallocKillList);
}

void addMallocKill(void* ptr) {
    if (!mallocKillList) {
        mallocKillList = calloc(1, sizeof(void*));
    } else {
        mallocKillList = realloc(mallocKillList, sizeof(void*) * (mallocKillListLength + 1));
    }

    mallocKillList[mallocKillListLength] = ptr;
    mallocKillListLength++;
}
```

After changing the functions also don't forget to initalize list length as 0:

```
unsigned int mallocKillListLength = 0;
```

You also miss "addMallocKill" call in a loop in your code right after:

```
pNetwork->rawHiddenNodes[i] = (struct rawHiddenNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct rawHiddenNode) * HL[i]);
```

I also suggest you to get used to either clearing up the memory using memset yourself after you allocate it via malloc or just use calloc at all times. Valgrind was complaining all over your code due to uninitialized variables.

Here is a link to full code:
https://www.onlinegdb.com/GMfaVgo4-